# SQL statement for count of different ranges

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, geopackage

In QGIS, I want to make a SQL-statement which should return the counts of different year ranges e.g. in column 1 should be the total count for distinct values for all years, in column 2 1950-1990, in column 3 1991-2000..

My statement looks like

```
  select column_1, count (distinct column_2), 
  (select count (distinct column_2) from db1 where year between 1950 AND 1990) 
  from db1 
  group by column_1
```

The result for `column_1` (count distinct values for `column_2` for all years) is fine, however for the range of 1950 to 1990, there is the same value for all rows of `column_1`.

Comment: There is no GIS element to this question, and therefore better asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question right (it is a little confusing with your desired column names having the same name as your existing column names), it should be something like this:

```sql
SELECT all_years, _1950_1990, _1991_2000 FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as all_years FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "year" FROM db1) AS temp1), 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as _1950_1990 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "year" FROM db1 WHERE "year" BETWEEN 1950 AND 1990) AS temp2),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as _1991_2000 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "year" FROM db1 WHERE "year" BETWEEN 1991 AND 2000) AS temp3);
```

[image]

According to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732410/4227297), using `COUNT (DISTINCT X)` is very slow, hence making `SELECT DISTINCT` subqueries first.